# How to make Style.Triggers trigger a different named style to be applied

Tags: wpf, triggers, styles, setter

Lets say I have the below:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true"> 
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers> 
</Style>
```

This works fine and there is nothing too much wrong here, but it is a fairly simple case. What happens if I want to have the IsFocused style state listed as a exsplicit style how do reference that style as being the IsFocused style, i.e.

```
<Style x:key="ActiveStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
           -- Here I want to reference ActiveStyle and not copy the copy the setters
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers> 
</Style>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think you can however, you can reuse a style this way :

```
<Style x:Key="ActiveStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource ActiveStyle}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />
</Style>
```

I don't see another solution :(

Answer (score 9):

There is yet a third way to do this.

Create two named control templates for your control:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="NotFocused" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">  
    . . .
</ControlTemplate>  

<ControlTemplate x:Key="Focused" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">   
    . . .
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then you create a default style for the TextBox with the triggers in it:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">   
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Focused}" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource NotFocused}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Tony

Comment: This causes an exception for me: “Style object is not allowed to affect the Style property of the object to which it applies.” It's kind of obvious, how can a style change itself to some other style but still continue to work?

Comment: I could have sworn I had an example of this in my application, but I can't find it now.  I don't recall that error occurring in my development, which doesn't mean anything, really.  I'll have to play with this sometime when I have a few minutes to spare.

Comment: @svick: I have edited my example so it now uses code that works.  It may not be totally relevant to the original question now as it uses control templates and a default style.  But this does work.

Answer (score 8):

WPF is providing a special property for this FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle So go ahead and assign that :)

```
<TextBox FocusVisualStyle="{StaticResource ActiveStyle}" .....
```

Or another way using setters

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
 <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
 <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray" />    
 <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" >
  <Setter.Value>
    <Style x:key="ActiveStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
       <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
       <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
    </Style>
   </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
 </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

My situation involved needing to display a lock/unlock icon image in the viewbox of a button.  Unfortunately, there is no direct property for Content on the viewbox.  Based on the response above from @Tony, here is a working example that incorporated his answer for my situation.

```
<Button Padding="5 0" Margin="0" Cursor="Hand" Style="{StaticResource IconButton}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Height="20" Width="20">
            <ContentControl >
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Open" TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource LockOpenIcon}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Closed" TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource LockClosedIcon}" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </ContentControl.Resources>
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" >
                        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Open}" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=WorkflowAccessibility, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" Value="{x:Static da:GatewayWorkflowAccessibility.VisibleDisabled}">
                                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Closed}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </Viewbox>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```