# How to have multiple window resource styles for same element type in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an element in my window, as below:

```
<Grid>        
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Label Name="StatisticsLabel" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"></Label>
        <RichTextBox Style="{StaticResource FocusMode}" Name="RichTextBox1"  />            
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

I would like to swith between two styles at runtime depending of the state I need the control to be in.

I had assumed I could use the following code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Name="FocusMode" TargetType="RichTextBox">
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"></Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Name="NormalMode" TargetType="RichTextBox">
        <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"></Setter>            
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Of course this isn't working.

Why does WPF not support multiple styles per element? Seems like a pretty basic requirement?

Otherwise, how do I achieve this?

Comment: Hello Shenku, this seems to me like a perfect application for triggers in only one style. When you say you'd like to change your style depending on the state you need the control to be in, what gives you the information about the state you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry figured it out, instead of x:Name use x:Key as below:

```
<Window.Resources>
<Style x:Key="FocusMode" TargetType="RichTextBox">
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"></Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="NormalMode" TargetType="RichTextBox">
    <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"></Setter>            
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a look at style triggers.  You can probably get a good start on the subject from this post: [How to make Style.Triggers trigger a different named style to be applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1183982/wpf-how-to-make-style-triggers-trigger-a-different-named-style-to-be-applied)

Comment: Hi Erik, not what I am looking for right now but that will be very handy eventually, thanks!